How to pass in variables during redirect in HTML using Jinja syntax?
I have the following code:
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("login.html")
    elif request.method == "POST":
        username, password = request.form.get("username"), request.form.get("password")
        if validate_login(username, password):
            return redirect("/home.html")
        else:
            return render_template("login.html", login_message="Invalid username or password!")

with the following home.html file:
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    Hello {{ username }}, your password is {{ password }}!
{% endblock %}

The point here is that I am finding some ways to pass in variables to home.html using the redirect function (just like the last line of the code render_template), but after some intense google searches, I still can't find a way to do so. Do anyone know how to do this?

I'm assuming you're using flask as your routing engine.
If so, instead of redirecting to a bare html url, you can redirect to a new route. Something like:
if validate_login(username, password):
    return redirect(f"/home/{username}")

Then have that route render the home.html template using the variable as normal:
@app.route("/home/<username>")
def user_home(username):
    return render_template("home.html", username=username)

For additional variables you need, you could either have the user_home function retrieve them and pass them along to the template, or use some middleware function to add additional data to the user's request.
